# Cannot log into Microsoft apps on Windows 10

Tags: windows-10, login, sticky-notes, microsoft-store

I cannot log in Microsoft apps such as Stick Notes, MS Excel, Microsoft Store, etc.

Whether I try log in by password, SMS code, email code, all failed.
Actually my log-in was successful, but it requires logging in again.

Log-in on the web browser is okay, so I can see my log in attempts on MS my profile -> security tap.
It shows that I logged in successfully by 'Edge' browser when I tried logging in to Stick Notes or MS Excel.

It happens on all MS apps on my desktop PC but it does not happen on my laptop.
Very weired.

Comment: Go to Settings, Apps, and the scroll down to the Store app. Both Repair and Reset the App.  Close out, restart and test the Store again.

Comment: @John Thank you for your advice, but it didn't work. Now Sticky Notes was uninstalled without any notice... very strange

Comment: Thanks. Now open cmd.exe with Run as Administrator. Run dism.exe  /online  /cleanup-image  /restorehealth  . Then run SFC /SCANNOW.  Again (when done) restart and test.

Comment: Is the account you're using a Microsoft account? Is it a Microsoft 365 account? Why are you trying to login to Office apps and Sticky Notes? And are you logged into the computer using a Microsoft account or just a local account?

Comment: @music2myear The login problem happens when I log in Sticky Notes, MS Excel, and Microsoft store with my personal Microsoft account (myself@gmail.com). I have another Microsoft Account from my school (myself@myuniversity.edu) I can log in successfully (I think this is because my school gives Office 365 privilege to alumni)

Comment: @John There was no problem found from SFC /SCANNOW

Comment: @music2myear It is my personal Microsoft Account. When I log into Sticky Notes, the notes are synced with my another computer and my mobile app (OneNote). Somehow Stick Notes was uninstalled so I need to log in Microsoft Store to re-install Sticky Notes. If I log in MS Excel, I can save files in my OneDrive.

Comment: Did you run DISM prior to running SFC?  You need to do that.

Comment: @John Of course I did it

Comment: Thank you. So that being the case, the error is deeper than the  first and easiest corrective tools can manage.  (1) Make a new, test Windows User Profile. Log into the new profile. See if the Store is working properly. If so, your main user profile is damaged and needs to be replaced.  (2) If the profile appears to be working fine, then run a Windows 10 Repair Install from the Microsoft Media Creation Link. Use the second link and run in place or download to a USB key and run Setup from the key.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

That should be an Windows 10 authetication issue. You should check your Windows 10 license.